# NV or AMD for mining

Tags: gpu-mining

Which one delivers more coins per watt?

AMD or Nvidia? And am I right when I think that always the newest generation of a card is the best for mining?

Comment: IMHO this question is too broad. Choose specific cards to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of raw performance, Nvidia and AMD compare favorably. Once electricity usage is factored in, Nvidia wins out with far higher efficiency in the current round of technology.

http://monerobechmarks.byethost5.com/index.php?i=1

In terms of Nvidia cards, the GTX 1070 seems to be at a good price/performance/efficiency inflection point.

Comment: On the very link you shared, the RX 470 and RX 480 seem to be more efficient.

Comment: Indeed, they are slightly more efficient. The 1070 is comparable though and much faster for gaming, so depending upon what you use the card for I think you'll get more bang for your buck for the newer nvidia 1070.